# Batch-file for mysqldump to backup each database into a separate file

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2008, mysql

Trying to create a batch (cmd) file for backing up each database into a separate file.
Databases are created/deleted often, so batch file needs to grab current db names everytime it runs and backup each one of them.

Here is how I want it to be:

```
mysql -e "show databases" -u root --password=1234
mysqldump %dbname% -u root --password=1234 > S:\Backup\MySQL\%dbname%.sql
```

Is it possible to do in a batch file?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I just fixed the bug in my answer. Please try it now...

Comment: My solution seems slightly simplier, but I was too late =)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This can be run directly in cmd (I wrapped the line but it should not be wrapped):

```
mysql.exe -uroot -p1234 -s -N -e "SHOW DATABASES" |
  for /F "usebackq" %D in (`findstr /V "information_schema performance_schema"`)
    do mysqldump %D -uroot -p1234 > S:\Backup\MySQL\%D.sql
```

In a batch file you will need to escape % with an additional %, that is use `%%D`.

**Batch File**

```
mysql.exe -uroot -p1234 -s -N -e "SHOW DATABASES" |
  for /F "usebackq" %%D in (`findstr /V "information_schema performance_schema"`)
    do mysqldump %%D -uroot -p1234 > S:\Backup\MySQL\%%D.sql
```

Comment: Great! Where have you been before? =)

Comment: By "not be wrapped" @newtover means that all the lines have to be in one line, otherwise you will get syntax error.

Comment: some how but this batch file code is not working for me. it throws `The syntax of the command is incorrect.` error every time

Comment: @JubinPatel just use this script in one line (without new lines)

Comment: I'm in love with you. :)

Comment: @gramgram, to be honest, this is the answer I am really proud of. I am glad you like it too :)

Comment: @newtover: no good answer can take place without a good question asked first. =))

Answer (score 17):

You are going to love this one

Have the information_schema database construct a DOS Batch File to perform the mysqldumps in parallel

```
set MYSQLUSER=root
set MYSQLPASS=1234
set BATCHFILE=S:\Backup\MySQL\Batch_mysqldump.bat 
set DUMPPATH=S:\Backup\MySQL
echo @echo off > %BATCHFILE% 
echo cd %DUMPPATH% >> %BATCHFILE% 
mysql -u%MYSQLUSER% -p%MYSQLPASS% -AN -e"SELECT CONCAT('start mysqldump -u%MYSQLUSER% -p%MYSQLPASS% --routines --triggers ',schema_name,' > ',schema_name,'.sql') FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema','performance_schema')" >> %BATCHFILE% 
type %BATCHFILE%
```

Just run like any DOS Batch File

Make sure you have the correct username and password to connect to mysql

I just tried it out to make sure

```
C:\>set MYSQLUSER=lwdba

C:\>set MYSQLPASS=<hidden>

C:\>set BATCHFILE=C:\LWDBA\Batch_mysqldump.bat

C:\>set DUMPPATH=C:\LWDBA

C:\>echo @echo off > %BATCHFILE%

C:\>echo cd %DUMPPATH% >> %BATCHFILE%

C:\>mysql -u%MYSQLUSER% -p%MYSQLPASS% -AN -Bse"SELECT CONCAT('start mysqldump -u%MYSQLUSER% -p%MYSQLPASS% --routines --triggers ',schema_nam
e,' > ',schema_name,'.sql') FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema','performance_schema')" >> %BATCH
FILE%

C:\>type %BATCHFILE%
@echo off
cd C:\LWDBA
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers a1ex07 > a1ex07.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers annarbor > annarbor.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers dilyan_kn > dilyan_kn.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers dtest > dtest.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers dude > dude.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers example > example.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers fed > fed.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers friends > friends.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers giannosfor > giannosfor.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers javier > javier.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers johnlocke > johnlocke.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers junk > junk.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers lovesh > lovesh.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers mysql > mysql.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers nwwatson > nwwatson.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers part > part.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers preeti > preeti.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers prefixdb > prefixdb.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers replagdb > replagdb.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers rollup_test > rollup_test.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers sample > sample.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers stuff > stuff.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers table_test > table_test.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers tagmediatest > tagmediatest.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers targetdb > targetdb.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers test > test.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers test_mysqldb > test_mysqldb.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers tostinni > tostinni.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers user1267617 > user1267617.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers user391986 > user391986.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers utility > utility.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers veto > veto.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers vito > vito.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers zipcodes > zipcodes.sql
```

Comment: This is an interesting one. But I get an error message: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server versi
on for the right syntax to use near '.sql') FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('information_s' at line 1

Comment: Good one! There are couple of things I needed to change like \\ instead of \, also there is no need to "start mysqldump" in a separate window for each command... I will post my answer and will accept yours. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA you sir, are a total bad ass.

Answer (score 2):

hey rolando i combined your code with some other code from the internet to dump all databases to different files and compress it in one file with date-time stamp and finally delete files older than 60 days
cheers

```
@echo off
CLS
cd c:\temp
set MYSQLUSER=root
set MYSQLPASS=PassWord
set BATCHFILE=c:\temp\Batch_mysqldump.bat 
set DUMPPATH=c:\temp
SET backuptime=%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~10,4%-%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%
SET backuptimelog=%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~10,4% %TIME:~0,2%:%TIME:~3,2%:%TIME:~6,2%
echo starting MySqlDump at %backuptime%
echo ------ starting MySqlDump at %backuptimelog% ------   >> "Z:\-=macine backup=-\sqldump\sqldump.log"
echo Running dump...   
set 7zip_path=
mkdir "%backuptime%" >> "Z:\-=macine backup=-\sqldump\sqldump.log"
cd "c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin"
echo @echo off > %BATCHFILE% 
echo cd %DUMPPATH% >> %BATCHFILE% 
echo copy "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe" "c:\temp\%backuptime%" >> %BATCHFILE% 
echo cd "%backuptime%" >> %BATCHFILE% 
mysql -u%MYSQLUSER% -p%MYSQLPASS% -AN -e"SELECT CONCAT('mysqldump -u%MYSQLUSER% -p%MYSQLPASS% ' ,schema_name,' --result-file=',schema_name,'.sql') FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema','performance_schema')" >> %BATCHFILE% 
echo exit >> %BATCHFILE%
start /wait %BATCHFILE% 
echo Compressing bk_%backuptime%.sql...
SET ziptime=%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~10,4% %TIME:~0,2%:%TIME:~3,2%:%TIME:~6,2%
echo starting 7zip compression at %ziptime%
echo starting 7zip compression at %ziptime% >> "Z:\-=macine backup=-\sqldump\sqldump.log"
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z -m0=PPMd "Z:\-=macine backup=-\sqldump\bk_%backuptime%.7z" "c:\temp\%backuptime%" >> "Z:\-=macine backup=-\sqldump\sqldump.log"
 echo Deleting the SQL file ...   
 rmdir /s /q "c:\temp\%backuptime%" >> "Z:\-=macine backup=-\sqldump\sqldump.log"
 echo deleting files older than 60 days
 echo deleting files older than 60 days >> "Z:\-=macine backup=-\sqldump\sqldump.log"
 forfiles -p "Z:\-=macine backup=-\sqldump" -s -m *.* /D -60 /C "cmd /c del @path" >> "Z:\-=macine backup=-\sqldump\sqldump.log"
 SET finishtime=%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~10,4% %TIME:~0,2%:%TIME:~3,2%:%TIME:~6,2%
 echo ------ Done at %finishtime%! ------ >> "Z:\-=macine backup=-\sqldump\sqldump.log"
 echo Done at %finishtime%!
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, First... It's possible that I'm using a different version of SQL than you, and im sorry if thats the case, you didn't list your version in your question so I'm just going to give you what works with mine.

I have the first part of this done, but I'm still working on the backing up of the DB's.

```
sqlcmd -U %USER% -P %PASSWORD% -Q"SELECT name FROM sys.databases" > c:\JHA\Synergy\SQL_db_list.txt
```

There are other triggers that can be used, but it sounds like you're going to be on the actual machine that has SQL installed, correct? If this is the case, it should default the IP to connect to SQL to 127.0.0.1 or localhost, etc.

What I'm thinking I'm going to have to do for this is create a file in the batch script that I will call further down that will send the commands line by line, similar to what is done in the FTP process with Batch Scripts.

I'll update this when I get it.

Comment: It does not matter which version of MySQL you use. mysqldump works same way on all versions. If I'm running a batch file - oh yes, I'm on the local machine. 127.0.0.1 - is a localhost, you are right on this one.

Comment: @Radio - You voted me down for asking if you were using a different version of SQL? Your commands dont work on my version of SQL... mysqldump does not work with MSSQL, which I am using, though the commands should be very similar. I'm running MSSQL, the most common version of SQL.

Comment: You are not reading my question. It's not related to MSSQL or any other database. It's related only to MySQL. Just read please.

Comment: You should learn to express yourself verbally better... Noone on here is a mind reader. Please see to it that you adhear to the proper format of questions and seek some guidance from the FAQ. 
[ http://stackoverflow.com/faq ]

Comment: First of all, we are chatting online, this got nothing to do with VERBAL term. Secondly my original post clearly shows: mysql tag and mysqldump in the topic. What is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the answers but none of them worked as expected, here is my solution for backup but it will create a single file for mysql and other user databases.

```
set USERNAME=root
set PASSWORD=1234
set TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~10,4%.%DATE:~4,2%.%DATE:~7,2%-%TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~6,2%
set BACKUPPATH=D:\Backup\MySql\

if not exist %BACKUPPATH% md %BACKUPPATH%

mysqldump --all-databases --result-file="%BACKUPPATH%%TIMESTAMP%.sql" --user=%USERNAME% --password=%PASSWORD%
```

Comment: for mysqldump the syntax you mentioned will not work as we have to follow the sequence.
mysqldump -h {hostname} -u {usernamne} -p{password} {dbName} > path/to/store/sql/file.

Comment: @SumanEStatic The script is working fine right now and dumps dbs perfectly... MySQL Server 5.5

Answer (score 0):

This script is a bit more "professional" in the sense that it notifies someone when one DB dump failed and which one failed. Though, I had it not backing up all databases but only chosen ones. This can be fixed easily by changing the `SET DBS=` content by a command getting all databases.

**EDIT: New version remove the warning message**

```
@ECHO OFF

:: Configuration part
SET BACKUP_PATH=Backup-MySQL8
SET PHP=C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\php.exe
SET MAIL_TO=to_an_email@domain.com
SET MAIL_FROM=from_an_email@domain.com

SET MYSQL_PATH=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin
SET MYSQL_USER=root
SET MYSQL_PASS=mypassword
SET DBS=database_name1 database_name2


:: Software part
if not exist %BACKUP_PATH% md %BACKUP_PATH%

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET hasError=0
SET dbsInError=
SET CONFIG_FILE=backup-mysql.cnf

DEL /F /Q %BACKUP_PATH%\* 

echo [mysqldump] > %CONFIG_FILE%
echo user=%MYSQL_USER% >> %CONFIG_FILE%
echo password=%MYSQL_PASS% >> %CONFIG_FILE%

(for %%a in (%DBS%) do (
    "%MYSQL_PATH%\mysqldump.exe" --defaults-extra-file=%CONFIG_FILE% --routines --triggers %%a > %BACKUP_PATH%\%%a.sql
    IF NOT !ERRORLEVEL! == 0 (
        SET hasError=1
        DEL %BACKUP_PATH%\%%a.sql
        SET dbsInError=!dbsInError! %%a
    )
))

DEL %CONFIG_FILE%

IF !hasError! == 1 (
    echo Error... sending email
    "%PHP%" -r "echo (mail('%MAIL_TO%', 'Backup MySQL failed', 'The following database dump failed:!dbsInError!', 'From: %MAIL_FROM%') ? 'Sent' : 'Failed:' . print_r(error_get_last()));"
    echo.
)

echo Backup ended
```

Answer (score -1):

Im no DOS hacker,but I added one correction to my copy of the batch file to account for the whitespace character in the curtime variable if time is before 10 am. 
I added this line to my batch file after the for loops:

```
if "%curtime:~0,1%"==" " set curtime=0%curtime:~1,3%
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this straight forward approach:

```
mysqldump databaseName -u root --password=rootPass >  "path\myDBbackup.sql"
```

**steps:**
1. type the above code in your text editor and save it as batch file e.g. mybatch.bat
2. change directory(cd) to d location you save the batch file to, from your command prompt
3. type the name of your batch file and hit enter e.g. mybatch.bat
4. check the location for your DB schema i.e. path

Comment: This is not what the question is about