# CMD: Iterate stdin piped from another command

Tags: windows, cmd

A recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472804/batch-file-for-mysqldump-to-backup-each-database-into-a-separate-file) contains a problem that I many times used to think about but still do not know if it has an elegant solution:

Suppose, I have a command that forms a list of filenames or directories: `dir /B /AD`. Then, I would like to pipe the result of the command to an iterator that would do something with each filename.

How can I do it?

Instead of piping, one can certainly use backtick version of the `for`:

```
for /F "usebackq" %F in (`dir /B /AD`) do @echo %F
```

But I am interested here in getting the data from stdin, so that I would not hardcode the source of the filenames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I happen to have found a solution myself:

```
dir /B /AD | for /F "usebackq" %F in (`findstr "."`) do @echo %F
```

This is even better than I thought, because it allows filtering directly in backticks expression. For example to exclude some particular filenames (.svn and _lib) I can write:

```
dir /AD /B | for /F "usebackq" %F in (`findstr /V "\.svn _lib"`) do @echo %F
```